# Probability on a 8x8 chessboard with pieces and kings. What is the chance the piece can be captured?

Tags: probability, chessboard

I recently started playing chess (damn quarantine) and came up with this problem.

Supposing we have a blank 8x8 chessboard.
We pick a spot at random and place a special black piece which **cannot move**.
Then pick two another spots at random and place two white kings. (the kings move according to normal chess rules)

> Q: What are the chances that either king could capture the black
>   piece?
>   If instead of kings we had white rooks, what would the answer be?

Additionaly, if we repeat the same problem with two black pieces which both have to be captured and two white kings what would the answer be?

Comment: Ummm... if the king is adjacent to the piece, then it can; if not, not.  Count the squares.

Comment: I don't think you have understood the question. The black piece could be in different 64 squares. the king cannot be in 64x8 because he would be out of the board in many instances. I am not sure how to calculate something like that. What about the other cases as well?

Comment: I understand this completely.  Split the problem into the $6 \times 6$ cases where the piece can be "surrounded," and then the remaining cases.

Comment: Break it into 3 cases; where the black piece is in the interior, on an edge, or on a corner.  For instance the probability it is in the interior is 36/64.  Then find out for each case the number of adjacent squares and find the probability one of the kings is in an adjacent square.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense. Sorry for being rude. Thank you for explaining

Comment: The generalization in the last paragraph is unclear. Should white be able to capture both black pieces, or does it count as a success if white can capture either of the two black pieces?

Comment: Both pieces. I edited the post to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I'm writing up the solution for the two black pieces and will hopefully be posting it shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one black piece and two white kings:

The black piece has $8$ neighbouring squares with probability $\frac{6^2}{8^2}=\frac9{16}$, $3$ neighbouring squares with probability $\frac4{8^2}=\frac1{16}$ and $5$ neighbouring squares with the remaining probability $1-\frac9{16}-\frac1{16}=\frac38$. If the black piece has $k$ neighbours, the probability that it cannot be captured by the two white kings is $\frac{\binom{63-k}2}{\binom{63}2}=\frac{(63-k)(62-k)}{63\cdot62}$. Thus the probability that the black piece cannot be captured by either king is

$$
\frac{\frac9{16}(63-8)(62-8)+\frac1{16}(63-3)(62-3)+\frac38(63-5)(62-5)}{63\cdot62}=\frac{1193}{1488}\approx80.2\%\;.
$$

For one black piece and two white rooks:

The number of squares from which a given square can be attacked by a rook is the same for all squares, namely $2\cdot7=14$. Thus the probability that the black piece cannot be captured by either rook is

$$
\frac{(63-14)(62-14)}{63\cdot62}=\frac{56}{93}\approx60.2\%\;.
$$

For the cases with two black pieces, I’ll wait for your reply to my comment under the question.

Comment: This stuff is amazing! I wish I had spent time learning how to calculate something like that when I was younger. I will try to understand your explanation as much as I can. Thank you for taking the time to write it all out.

Comment: Okay, I have spent a lot of time and I think I understand now. I also learnt about binomial coefficients today. For once I find math really fascinating. Thank you again.